# Cannot pass AuthenticationManager to custom filter by @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I'm trying pass filter JWTLoginFilter to WebSecurityConfig WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter by @Autowired annotation. The problem arise when JWTLoginFilter try get AuthenticationManager from WebSecurityConfig.

When I start server, I get this error:

> Description:
>
> The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form
>   a cycle:
>
> JWTLoginFilter defined in file
>   [C:\Users\user\workspace\backend\target\classes\pl\dn\schoolsystem\service\jwt\JWTLoginFilter.class]
>
> webSecurityConfig (field
>   pl.dn.schoolsystem.service.jwt.JWTLoginFilter
>   pl.dn.schoolsystem.config.WebSecurityConfig.jwtLoginFilter)

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al5lE.png)

I think this circular dependency injection. I got stuck on this and i have no idea how to solve it.

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

    @Autowired
    JWTLoginFilter jwtLoginFilter;

    private static final String Salt = "salt"; // should be protected better

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12, new SecureRandom(Salt.getBytes()));
    }

    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
       @Override
       public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
           return super.authenticationManagerBean();
       }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().
        authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()

        .and()

        //.addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()), 
                //UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtLoginFilter, 
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);        
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

}
```

JWTLoginFilter:

```
@Component
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter{

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public JWTLoginFilter(@Value("/login") String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException,
            IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("Jestem w JwtLogginFilter.attemptAuthentication -------------------------------------");

        AccountCredentials creds = new ObjectMapper()
            .readValue(req.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);

        User user = userService.findByUsername(creds.getUsername());

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword(),
                        user.getAuthorities()
                        )
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("Jestem w JWTLogginFilter.successfulAuthentication -------------------------------------- ");

        System.out.println("authResult.getName(): " + authResult.getName());
        TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, authResult.getName());

    }



}
```

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4. Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `WebSecurityConfig` explicitly requests `JWTLoginFilter` to be injected in it, and `JWTLoginFilter` requests `AuthenticationManager` to be injected in its constructor. `AuthenticationManager` is supplied by `WebSecurityConfig`, so you have a circular dependency.

Remove `@Component` annotation from `JWTLoginFilter` and define the filter as a bean in `WebSecurityConfig`:

```
@Bean
public JWTLoginFilter jwtLoginFilter() {
    return new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager());
}
```

You will probably also need to inject `UserService` manually in this method (for example, via constructor).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's help me so much. Thanks your suggestion I solve my problem :).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for help [Roman Puchkovskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7637120/roman-puchkovskiy) I can correct my code. Final result of my code:

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;


    private static final String Salt = "salt"; // should be protected better

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12, new SecureRandom(Salt.getBytes()));
    }

    @Bean
    public JWTLoginFilter jwtLoginFilter() throws Exception {
        return new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().
        authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()

        .and()

//      .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()), 
//              UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtLoginFilter(), 
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);        
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

}
```

JWTLoginFilter:

```
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter{

    @Autowired
    UserService userService; 

    public JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException,
            IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("Jestem w JwtLogginFilter.attemptAuthentication -------------------------------------");

        AccountCredentials creds = new ObjectMapper()
            .readValue(req.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);

        User user = userService.findByUsername(creds.getUsername());

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword(),
                        user.getAuthorities()
                        )
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("Jestem w JWTLogginFilter.successfulAuthentication -------------------------------------- ");

        System.out.println("authResult.getName(): " + authResult.getName());

        TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, authResult);

    }



}
```