# AuthenticationProcessingFilter and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter causing circular dependency

Tags: java, spring

In my Spring boot app, I have the following two classes:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        // TODO re-enable csrf after dev is done
        .csrf()
            .disable()
            // we must specify ordering for our custom filter, otherwise it
            // doesn't work
            .addFilterAfter(jwtAuthenticationFilter,
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // we don't need Session, as we are using jwt instead. Sessions
            // are harder to scale and manage
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
   }
}
```

and:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends
        AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    /*
     * we must set authentication manager for our custom filter, otherwise it
     * errors out
     */
    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationManager(
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

`JwtAuthenticationFilter` depends on an `AuthenticationManager` bean through its `setAuthenticationManager` method, but that bean gets created in `AppSecurityConfig` which has `JwtAuthenticationFilter` autowired in. This whole thing creates a circular dependency. 
How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does it prevent the context to be fully initialized ?
IMHO there 2 different kind of dependencies involved here:
One **static** dependency: Both your classes depends on AuthenticationManager. And AppSecurityConfig depends on JwtAuthenticationFilter. Nothing circular so far.
And one **dynamic** dependency, where JwtAuthenticationFilter depends on AppSecurityConfig for its runtime initialization.

Comment: Also it's not clear from the code snippet why you need a JwtAuthenticationFilter inside AppSecurityConfig. I would try to remove this dependency.

Comment: I don't get this error when running in eclipse, but when I build the app and refresh its gradle dependencies in terminal using `sudo ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` it errors: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: I updated the code to show why I need `JWTAuthenticationFilter` in `AppSecurityConfig`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, `AuthenticationManager` which is needed in `JWTAuthenticationFilter` is initialized in `AppSecurityConfig`, and `AppSecurityConfig` has `JWTAuthenticationFilter` wired in. Doesn't this form a circular dependency ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this issue by following what was suggested here: 
[Cannot pass AuthenticationManager to custom filter by @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736385/cannot-pass-authenticationmanager-to-custom-filter-by-autowired)

I removed `@Component` from `JwtAuthenticationFilter` and instead of autowiring `JwtAuthenticationFilter` to `WebSecurityConfig` class, I defined the bean there:

```
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter JwtAuthenticationFilter() {
    return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
}
```